# SpecificAvroDeserializer and "specifc.avro.reader"

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have a question about SpecificAvroDeserializer because of class name, I always assumed, SpecificAvroSerializer will produce SpecificRecord and SpecificAvroDeserializer will be able to consume it.

To my surprise, if I don't set the 'specific.avro.reader' property, SpecificAvroDeserializer tries to read byte array as GenericRecord because of the following line of code at the class "AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer" (https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java)..

```
private DatumReader getDatumReader(Schema writerSchema, Schema readerSchema) {
boolean writerSchemaIsPrimitive =
    AvroSchemaUtils.getPrimitiveSchemas().values().contains(writerSchema);
// do not use SpecificDatumReader if writerSchema is a primitive
if (useSpecificAvroReader && !writerSchemaIsPrimitive) {
  if (readerSchema == null) {
    readerSchema = getReaderSchema(writerSchema);
  }
  return new SpecificDatumReader(writerSchema, readerSchema);
} else {
  if (readerSchema == null) {
    return new GenericDatumReader(writerSchema);
  }
  return new GenericDatumReader(writerSchema, readerSchema);
}
```

}

I thought the constructor of the SpecificAvroDeserializer should set this but it does not.. (https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serde/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/streams/serdes/avro/SpecificAvroDeserializer.java)

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Might be a good issue to search for on the schema registry project

Comment: I would like to think it's false by default because your SpecificRecord type is not guaranteed to be on the classpath, but I agree that by explicitly trying to use that deserializer, you'd already have that class available as you'd be trying to read that specific object from the topic